# How is click action implemented in appium for chrome android

Tags: appium, appium-android

I know that the click action in iOS Safari is implemented with javascript, unless nativeWebTap capability is set to true (as reported [here](https://appiumpro.com/editions/36)), I cannot find a description of how the click action is implemented in chrome on a mobile device running android. Can somebody help gathering this information?

Comment: Please confirm if you are running with browser capability or app directly on Android

Answer (score 0):

Appium uses WebDriver API to test Web applications on Android Chrome browser, so basically it is using Chromedriver to make calls to Chrome DevTools and interact with DOM.

It is not like pure JS commands by default, but WebDriver API still allows you to send JS code for execution.